# Can we add multiple translations to a custom label in Salesforce?

Tags: customlabel

I wanted to add 3 language translations to one custom label, but I cannot see any option to do so. Is it possible in Salesforce?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the 3 languages are active in your org, use the translation related list on the custom label to add new translations.

> 1.From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Custom Labels, then select Custom Labels. 
>  2. Select the name of the custom label to open.
>  3.In the Translations related list, click New to enter a new translation or Edit next to the language to change a translation.
>  4. Select the Language you are translating into.
>  5.In the Translation Text field, enter the translated value. This text overrides the value specified in the label's Value field when a user's default language is the translation language.
>
>  6.Save your changes.

Source documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_translate_edit.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks, worked well for me.!!